# What do you call the activities between actual work?

Tags: word-choice

I've noticed that there are many cases where more time is spent on preparation and other things around the actual work that's intended to be done. For example, at school, very little time is spent learning - most of it is spent commuting, going from class to class, doing homework, waiting for the teacher, etc.

Similarly, as a web developer, I don't spend very much time actually writing code. I end up spending most of my time compiling projects, looking for bugs with our bug tracking system, updating the status of those bugs, etc.

What do we call these activities that aren't the focus of our time, but end up taking up a lot of it anyway?

edit: The word "peripheral" came to mind. I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for though.

Comment: In the Writing Biz it's called *staring at the screen* (formerly *the page*) or *not writing* and it's billed as *research*.

Comment: If you aren't learning by doing school homework assignments, then your teacher is almost certainly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Administrative tasks, housekeeping, documentation - they are all ancillary duties that are expected from you in addition to primary duties.

an·cil·lar·y  
/ˈansəˌlerē/

Adjective
Providing necessary support to the primary activities or operation of an organization, institution, industry, or system.

From http://www.google.com/search?q=ancillary+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari)

Comment: Mmm, I've never heard of ancillary before, but I think it fits. Also makes me think of auxiliary, which might also work.

Comment: I also like _ancillary_ for the purpose and also, it will be more suitable than _auxiliary_ since it pertains to the "necessary support" and not just any "additional support".

Comment: Interesting word, "ancillary." Derived from the Latin for slave, I believe. (This would be with reference to the e.g. administrative "duties," in relation to the main task.)

Answer (score 3):

The terms  *[maintenance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maintenance#Noun)* (“Actions performed to keep some machine or system functioning or in service”) and  *[preparation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preparation#Noun)* (“The act of preparing or getting ready”), while perhaps prosaic are still quite suitable terms for what you refer to.  Of course, some of what you refer to is just *[interruptions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interruption#Noun)* or   *[busy work](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/busy_work#Noun)* (“routine work of low priority undertaken for the sake of avoiding idleness”).

Idiomatic terms for the actions of dealing with items like you refer to include  *sharpening the saw*, popularized in  [Stephen Covey's](https://www.stephencovey.com/7habits/7habits-habit7.php) *The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People* (Habit 7: Sharpen the Saw) and *winding the clock*, a term that often appears in Le Carre's novels.

Answer (score 3):

I usually just call it *overhead*.

Answer (score 2):

You might call these activities *peripheral*.

Answer (score 2):

In the strictest sense, these are all *part* of the work, not alien to it.

Sometimes they may appear less important, less visible, less contributive to success or consume less effort. They are sometimes called *enabling* tasks, *appurtenant* tasks or *non-core* tasks.

*Non-core tasks* is the most meaningful and appropriate as it shows inclusivity while at the same time differentiating from the *core-task*.

In a well-organized system, "commuting, going from class to class, doing homework, waiting for the teacher, etc." all contribute to "education" along with conventional "learning."